# Is there a free Javascript push service with a high requests limit?

Tags: javascript, web-services, api, push

I'm currently using [Pubnub](http://www.pubnub.com), but i'll probably exceed the free quota. Is there any free js push service with a high quota?
The app  i'm developing is for a not-for-profit crowdbased service dedicated to monitor candidates' abuses in the brazilian political campaign this year.
(Sorry if i'm not making any sense, i'm very sleepy and caffeine isn't kicking in anymore)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about asking Pubnub to sponsor your effort with a free quota?

If you are seeing this old post, [PubNub's Free account](https://www.pubnub.com/pricing/) now allows up to 100 daily active devices, 1 million free messages per month, and all add-ons are free (forever).

Comment: We'll do that today. I was hoping for some more options, in case they say it's not possible.
Btw, the project is http://www.eleitor2010.com, and it uses the Ushahidi platform. I'm developing the social apps (Facebook and Orkut).